# How can I check which virtual desktop is active on windows 10 in python Script?

Tags: python, windows, automation, windows-10

I have multiple virtual desktops(say 4) on windows 10.I want to create a python script which changes the wallpaper whenever I switch to another virtual desktop.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: not yet, just thought of it and my thought stuck at the question above...